# filtering an array of objects by an array of strings

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm filtering an array of objects with the following code:

```
  filterCategory(category: [string]) {
    this.projects = this.projects.filter(project => project.category == category);
  }
```

It works to a degree but I want to refine it so it will return any object that has the category string within.

e.g.

```
project: [{
    name: "thing1"
    category: ["Design", "Web Design"]
  }, {
    name: "thing2"
    category: ["Web Design"]
  }, {
    name: "thing3"
    category: ["Design"]
  }, {
    name: "thing4"
    category: ["Design", "Web Design"]
  }]

filterCategory("Design")
```

filterCategory design currently will only return thing3 but I'd like it to return thing1, thing3, and thing4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's Array.indexOf will look at each array value for a match.

`project => project.category.indexOf(category) !== -1`

Comment: this worked! would you mind explaining what the -1 does at the end of the code?

Comment: The indexOf function returns -1 if the value is not found, since you're looking for matches you need to check that the return value is not -1. > -1 would be another equivalent means of performing the check.

Answer (score 1):

```
project => {
    for (let i = 0; i < project.category.length; i++) {
        if (project.category[i] === category) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another (less code) way to do this with ES6. Instead of `project => project.category.indexOf(category) !== -1` you can use **.includes** to do the same thing so the final code would look like this:

```
project => project.category.includes(category)
```

Worked the same for me just a little cleaner if you're using ES6.